# Python nfcpy showing acr122u usb device but not reading

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nfc, lib-nfc

I have nfcpy installed on my Raspberry Pi and when I run the following command

```
python -m nfc
```

I see the USB NFC Reader

I then created a python script called "test.py" and put the following code in it:

```
import nfc
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
print(clf)
```

When I run the test.py script it displays:

```
ACS ACR122U on usb:001:005
```

So the nfcpy is able to detect the reader no problem. Next I tried to take it to the next stage by trying to read a NFC tag using the following code:

```
import nfc
clf = nfc.ContactlessFrontend('usb')
clf.connect(rdwr={})
True
```

However, when I run this code the script is just listening for a tag and the green light on the reader turns on but no matter how many times i touch a NFC tag to the reader it just does not read anything and the script stays listening.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved this issue by doing a fresh installation of Rasbian and this time only installing nfcpy without installing libnfc or anything else. I believe problem was that installing libnfc caused a conflict of some kind